# Apache2 PHP5-FPM status page being over-writen by /var/www root webserver directory

Tags: apache, php

I'm trying to get PHP5-FPM status page working but the root .htaccess rules seem to be taking over the process.

I have this in the default.conf apache2

```
    <LocationMatch "/(ping|status)">
            SetHandler php5-fcgi-virt
            Action php5-fcgi-virt /php5-fpm-handler.fcgi virtual
    </LocationMatch>
```

Also how do I password protect the PHP5-FPM status page?

I am not able to access the http://www.domain.com/status page because of the current .htaccess rules in place so how can I over-write the rules from URL I just specified http://www.domain.com/status

Comment: what are the root .htaccess rules? are you saying you want to prevent .htaccess from overriding? here's how to protect: http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/restricting-access/

Comment: I think that is only specific to Nginx not apache.

Comment: ha, yes, sorry. here it is for apache: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PasswordBasicAuth

Comment: if would help if you showed us the rule that is in the .htaccess so we can see if it's possible to make a more specific rule that can override. Otherwise, no, the only option is to disable .htaccess...or map ping/status to another directory so that .htaccess isn't used.